# How to return char value in a function and store it in the main function

Tags: c

create function that prompts the user to enter a single character. The return value of the function be a `char` and will return the character value entered by the user.T his return value will be stored in a local variable, C, in `main()`. The initial default value of this character will be ' '. The question is how would I store it in the main if the local variable C is not global, and we cannot make it global. I have to use that C variable to finish my other functions. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char enterSingleChar();

int main()
{       
        char userChoice;
        int N = 0;
        char C = ' ';

        printf("Please choose one of the following choices below \n");
        printf("Enter/Change Character (C/c)\n");
        printf("Quit Program (Q/q) \n");

        scanf("%c", &userChoice);

        switch(userChoice)
        {       
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                        enterSingleChar();
                        break;
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                        printf("The program will now quit\n");
                        exit(1);
                default:
                        break;
        }
}

char enterSingleChar()
{
        char singleChar = ' ';
        printf("Please enter a single character \n");
        scanf(" %c", &singleChar);
        return singleChar;
}
```

Comment: You will need to assign the returned value by `enterSingleChar()`.

Comment: `char enterSingleChar();` has the wrong type and is deprecated. Use correct prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

```
    switch(userChoice)
    {       
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
                    C=enterSingleChar();
                    break;
            case 'Q':
            case 'q':
                    printf("The program will now quit\n");
                    exit(1);
            default:
                    break;
    }
```